# Getting Call to a member function view() on null

Tags: codeigniter, view, codeigniter-4

I am facing an issue with CodeIgniter 4: in my controller, if I am trying to  call a view it's showing below error.

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class Security extends BaseController{
/**
 * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
 * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
 * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $helpers = ['curl'];

public function index(){
    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('security/login');
}



}
```

And I am facing the below issue .

> CRITICAL - 2020-08-31 07:39:19 --> Call to a member function view() on
> null    #0 /var/www/html/codeignietor/system/CodeIgniter.php(918):
> App\Controllers\Security->index()
> #1 /var/www/html/codeignietor/system/CodeIgniter.php(404): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController()
> #2 /var/www/html/codeignietor/system/CodeIgniter.php(312): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest()
> #3 /var/www/html/codeignietor/public/index.php(45): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
> #4 /var/www/html/codeignietor/system/Commands/Server/rewrite.php(34): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')
> #5 {main}

Answer (score 1):

`$this->load` is null because that's not how you load views in CI4. You need to make sure you're looking at the CI4 version of the documentation if that is in fact the version you're using: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/views.html

In CI4, views are loaded by `echo`ing (or `return`ing) a call to `view()`:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class Security extends BaseController{
/**
 * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
 * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
 * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $helpers = ['curl'];

public function index(){
    //$this->load->view('head');
    //$this->load->view('security/login');
    echo view('head');
    echo view('security/login');
}
}
```

The way that you have presented in your code is how you loaded views in CI3. There are substantial changes between 3 and 4, so you should review the documentation altogether if this is your first jump between.

Comment: yes i got its it was my mistke CI4 is not stable version and its documents are not updated yet